# Class 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml' not found

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autoload

I've been struggling for the last day now getting the **Symfony Yaml parser** working in my application.

My `composer.json` looks like this;

```
{
"require": {
    "symfony/class-loader": "2.4.*@dev",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.4.*@dev",
    "facebook/php-sdk": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "src/"
    }
}
```

I'm using this in my application:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$parser = new Parser();
var_dump( $parser->parse( file_get_contents('config.yml') ) );
```

Then I get this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml' not found in /Projects/my-app/web/index.php on line 16

The UniversalClassLoader (from `"symfony/class-loader"`) works perfectly fine, and when I check what namespaces are loaded, the `Symfony\Component\Yaml` is the first one in the array.

My IDE ([PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)) is giving a squiggly line underneath the classname, *"Multiple definitions exist"*. One is going to the real vendor folder, the other one is referring to a file inside the `composer.phar` file (read-only).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Show your bootstrap code.  Especially where the autoloader is being created.

In general, you should probably use the composer generated autoload file as opposed to the S2 one.

This works:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$parser = new Parser();

var_dump( $parser->parse( file_get_contents('config.yml') ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @Cerad! It works now, I was using some weird combination of `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_namespaces.php`. Silly...